# What is the exhaust pressure of the Saturn V on the Apollo 11?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, simulations, rocket-science

I am trying to write some code to simulate rocket launches, and I am doing a proof of concept using the Apollo 11 as a model, to fill my values. When calculating thrust I am using the equation:

$$F = m \cdot V_e + (P_e - P_0)A_e \ ,$$

where $F$ is force/thrust, $m$ is mass and $V_e$ is velocity.

I have found $m$ dot and $V_e$ but can't find any values for $P_e$ or $A_e$.

Comment: What is (Pe-Po)Ae.?

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions Is a place to ask about stuff like this (the performance of Saturn, not your physics equations).

Comment: @trula  Pe is exhaust pressure and Po is atmospheric pressure Ae is the area of the booster